# PHP if file exists not working

Tags: php, slider, echo, nivo-slider

I am using a simple script that displays images in a jquery slideshow - these image filenames are listed in a .txt file, and change depending on the page you are on (im also using pagination in another script).

If the filename that is listed in the .txt file doesn't exist, I would like the image 'unavailable.jpg' to display instead...

The original script:

```
<?php
echo"
<div id='slider-wrapper'><div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>";
$photos=file("photos.txt");
foreach($photos as $image){
$item=explode("|",$image);
if($item[0]==$fields[0]){
$photo=trim($item[1]);
echo"<img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' />\n";
}
}
echo"
</div>
</div>
"?>
```

And here is my try at it...but it doesn't work properly- instead of the 'unavailable.jpg' image being displayed, it shows all of the images in the directory... :S Anyone have any ideas of what I might be doing wrong? :S

```
<?php
echo"
<div id='slider-wrapper'><div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>";
$photos=file("photos.txt");
foreach($photos as $image){
$item=explode("|",$image);
$photo=trim($item[1]);
if (file_exists("images/work/".$photo)) {
echo"<img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' />\n";
}
else{
echo"<img src='images/work/unavailable.jpg' alt='' />\n";
}
}
echo"
</div>
</div>
"?>
```

Instead of all the images showing, I only want images for that page to display. Here is an example of my text file:

```
1|image1.jpg
1|image2.jpg
1|image3.jpg
2|image1.jpg
2|image2.jpg
```

The 1 and 2 are for the pages 1 and 2, and they display the images that are listed. This all works fine in the above original script that I have posted, but it seems to break when I add the if file_exists.

Comment: What do you mean it shows all the images in the directory? If you make up a nonexistent file name, what is shown as the image?

Comment: If the file exist, shouldn't they be showed?

Comment: Also, what format are the `$image`'s? Why do you need to explode, select only one item, and trim?

Comment: I'm using jpeg files - I've edited the question to explain my setup a little more hopefully

Comment: It seems like you are using a flat list to store multi-dimensional data in a pretty strange way. You may want to look into storing this type of data in JSON or even XML format to make your coding a bit easier.

Comment: You omiited the `if($item[0]==$fields[0])`

Comment: Thank you so much ott for pointing that out! It gets rid of the whole directory of images showing, however, for the unavailable image, the outputted source shows it as just: <img src='images/work/' alt='' /> so no unavailable.jpg shows now... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to your images uses a relative path.  Are you sure the current working directory is the directory you think it is?

To verify do an `echo 'Current Working Directory: '.getcwd()."<br />\n"` and verify what directory you are in.

Its probably best to use a full file path to your image's directory so the script can be placed anywhere on your server.

Now if that is correct then you need to check that your script has permission to your image directory.  Typically php runs as `nobody:nobody` or `apache:apache` depending on your configuration.

The directories above as well as the files should have `644` (-rw-r--r--) or at a minimum `444` permission (-r--r--r--).

Try these two things and let us know if that solved your specific problem or not; I hope it does.

Comment: Thanks! All the images are displaying correctly, including the unavailable.jpg, but they are all listed at once. So instead of page 1 only displaying like 2 images, all the images from the directory will be displayed in the slideshow, including the unavailable.jpg files. Hope i'm making sense

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-add the test for $item[0] == $fields[0]:

```
<?php
    echo "<div id='slider-wrapper'><div id='slider' class='nivoSlider'>";
    $photos = file("photos.txt");
    foreach ($photos as $image) {
        $item = explode("|",$image);
        $photo = trim($item[1]);
        if (file_exists("images/work/".$photo)
            && $item[0] == $fields[0]
        ) {
            echo "<img src='images/work/$photo' alt='' />\n";
        } else {
            echo "<img src='images/work/unavailable.jpg' alt='' />\n";
        }
    }

    echo "</div></div>";
?>
```

Edit:
I just noticed that Ott pointed this out already in the comments. Are you still having the issue with unavailable.jpg?